# Divisible by 19?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

[image]

If $b$ has to be a whole number, I don't understand why $19$ HAS to be a factor of:

- $2$ (impossible)
- $a$ (also impossible because $a$ is a digit $(0-9)$)
- $5 \times 10^{m – 1} – 1$ (possible)

Because as I understand it, 19 could also be a factor of either:

- $2a$ (impossible since $a$ is a digit $(0-9)$ so max $18$)
- $2 \times (5 \times 10^{m – 1} – 1)$
- $a \times (5 \times 10^{m – 1} – 1)$
- $2a \times (5 \times 10^{m – 1} – 1)$

Maybe I'm totally wrong but it's like saying $(8\times 2) / 16$ is not a whole number because $16$ isn't a factor of $8$ or $2$ (But it is a factor of $8\times 2$).

Thanks in advance

Comment: if it divides a product it must divide into a subproduct or the whole product. so to divide into 2 a it must either divide into 2 or a . 19 being prime also plays a role i think you'll find.

Comment: It's true if you replace $19$ with any other prime: if a prime $p$ is a factor of $ab$, then $p$ is a factor of either $a$ or $b$ (or both).

Comment: this also comes from the fact that, for a number to divide a product, there must be a full factorization of the number in the product ( at least in the integers).  a primes full factorization, is 1 and itself,  the 1 can come from any part of the product, the prime has to come from a single part.

Comment: What about $2a(5\times10^{m-1}-1)?$

Comment: @GeorgeN.Missailidis true i forgot that one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$19$ is a prime number, which means that if $19$ is a factor of $ab$ it is a factor of $a$ or a factor of $b$.

So if $19$ is a factor of $a(bc)$ it is a factor of $a$ or a factor of $bc$. And if it is a factor of $bc$ it is a factor of $b$ or a factor of $c$.

Comment: I didn't know that about primes,  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @delivosa This property becomes the definition of a prime in more advanced work. To prove, first show that if $p,q$ are coprime then there are integers $m, n$ wth $mp+nq=1$ (Bezout). Now suppose that $p$ is a factor of $ab$ but not of $a$. Then $a,p$ are coprime and we can find $m,n$ with $ma+np=1$. Multiply this by $b$ so that $mab+npb=b$ and observe that $p$ is a factor of both terms on the left-hand side, so must also be a factor of $b$.

Comment: Thank you for that also, I'm going to study number theory now :)

Comment: $a(bc) = (ab)c$

Answer (score 1):

Prime $\,p\mid a_1\cdots a_n\,\Rightarrow\, p\mid a_i\,$ for some $i,\,$ i.e. if a prime divides a product then it must divide one of the factors of the product. This is an immediate consequence of the *Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic,* i.e. for every natural $> 1$ there $\rm\color{#0a0}{exists}$  a factorization into a product of primes that is $\rm\color{#c00}{unique}$ (up to order).

Indeed, $\,p b = a_1\cdots a_n\,$ thus by $\rm\color{#0a0}{existence}$ we can replace $b$ and the $a_i$ by their prime factorizations. Thus by $\rm\color{#c00}{uniqueness}$, since $p$ occurs in the LHS prime factorization, it must also occur in the RHS, so it occurs in the prime factorization of some $a_i,\,$ hence $\,p\mid a_i.$

**Remark** $ $ Conversely, the above *Prime Divisor Property* implies uniqueness of prime factorizations, hence it is *equivalent* to the uniqueness of prime factorizations.